# Iterating over JSON object with array from MS Graph API

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using node to call MS Graph API `v1.0/users`. It's returning fine and if I do `console.log(users)` I get something like the following:

```
{
  [
    {
       displayName: "bob dole"
    },
    {
       displayName: "steve stevenson"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to just output a list of display names.

```
  const users = await fetch.callApi(auth.apiConfig.uri, authResponse.accessToken);
  users.forEach(user => {
    console.log(user.displayName);
  })
```

This does not work. It results in `users.forEach` is not a function.  I'm sure this is a simple fix and it's related to the response being a single object, but I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Is the example you provided the exact structure of the object? The JSON you sent appears to be invalid, because the array doesn't have a key value. If this was the case, you'd be getting an invalid JSON error; can you clarify the data structure of the API response? What is the entire console output for `console.log(users)`?

Comment: Ah hah! I was only assuming the format because I couldn't see the top of the output due to my buffer size. Turns out `users.value.forEach()` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph API actually returns data in the following format

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
  value: [
    //objects here
  ],
}
```

So the fix was to change `users.forEach()` to `users.value.forEach()`.  Thanks to @zmehall for putting me on the right track.